# Why Local Inner class requires local variable Final? This Variable is in same method in which Local Inner class define

Tags: java, inner-classes

Why Local Inner class  requires local variable Final? This Variable is in same method in which Local Inner class define. **If we do not use final keyword then it will give compilation error.** [Please check the following program on ideone](http://ideone.com/Ql8tUW)

```
class LocalInnerClassTest2 {
    private String x="Outer2";
    public static void main(String [] args){
        LocalInnerClassTest2 test=new LocalInnerClassTest2();
        test.doStuff();
    }
    void doStuff(){
```

**//Why following local variable "final String z" requires final keyword**

```
    final String z="local variable";
    class MyInner {
        public void seeOuter(){
            System.out.println("Outer x is "+x);
            System.out.println("Local variable z is "+z);
        }
    }
    MyInner my=new MyInner();
    my.seeOuter();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an inner class gets a copy of the environment which is available to it when it is instantiated.

If you don't declare `z` as final you could have a situation like the following:

```
  String z = "variable";

  class MyInner {
        public void seeOuter(){
            System.out.println("Outer x is "+x);
            System.out.println("Local variable z is "+z);
        }
    }
  MyInner my=new MyInner();

  z = "another value";

  my.seeOuter();
```

But the context for `MyInner` is created upon instantiation, so this would lead to `seeOuter` accessing a different value of `z` (bound before it is changed) and this would be misleading (and wrong since you wouldn't expect it).